# I want to use search bar without using submit

Tags: php, html, get

When I type the search query I get the following url

```
http://localhost/bp/contactus.php?search=bvlfnfdl&submit=Submit
```

while I want it as

```
http://localhost/bp/contactus.php?search=bvlfnfdl
```

how to do that kindly help

Comment: tirgger on change input

Comment: Remove the `name` attribute of your submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 'name' on the submit button.

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
   <input type="text" name="search" />
   <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
```

And in then in your PHP you can just access the `$_GET['search']` to grab the searched data.

Comment: I know that but I want the link modified

Comment: What do you mean by this? This will remove the `&submit=submit` section